# OS X not bootable after full restore on Macbook 12"

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, recovery

just got usb->usbC cable and was able to do a full restore of my backup from MBA13" (2011)

Everything was OK, until reboot after recovery - recovered partition was not just bootable :(

Before the backup I fully updated MBA13 to OS X 10.10.3 (14D136) which was the final release until yesterday

I cannot find any info on this in the internet, but I have no errors, no any issues - just not bootable recovered partition

PS. on Option-key boot to select partition there is no main hdd in the list (only recovery partition is available)

Also, when open Select Boot utility from recovery menu - there is no available options at all, the same time Disk Utility shows partition like full of data, from Terminal I can see files

Answer (score 1):

The MacBook 12" uses hardware that hasn't been used in other Macs so far. Therefor the drivers are not yet included in the "latest" OS X which you can get via the App Store on your Macbook Air.

Your options

- Format & Reinstall the MacBook, use the migration assistant to "clone" data.
- Try reinstalling the MacBook via [internet-recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314), this might work with your data still in place, however, some apps might break due to the reinstall.
- Wait for a OS X release that includes the drivers, update your old MacBook, then clone again.

Comment: My old macbook is not with me anymore ) doing internet recovery right now